# Setting up routes for retrieving subset of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model that has it's own controller `Event`, on that model I have a flag that tells me if it's public or not, creating a subset of records. How can I set up my routes/controllers to be able to get the following routes:

`events/:id`
`events/public`
`events/public/:id`

Comment: your question is not well described. did you mean you want to create a custom method to retrieve custom data? did you find your routes using `rake routes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`resources :events` will give you the following paths:

```
/events
/events/:id
/events/:id/edit
# ... and so on
```

You can add the `public` flag to the routes providing custom routes path using `path` option:

```
resources :events, path: "events/(:flag)", constraints: {flag: 'public'}
```

This will give you the following paths:

```
/events
/events/public
/events/:id
/events/public/:id
/events/:id/edit
/events/public/:id/edit
```

When a path includes "public" you will have `params[:flag] = "public"` in the `EventsController`.

To generate paths including "public" you can use routes helper methods providing `flag` parameter:

```
events_path                  # => /events
events_path(flag: "public")  # => /events/public
```

Comment: This is a better solution than the one I had of declaring a collection resource on public. This way I don't need the other controller I created and it's much cleaner. Gotta do some refactoring first to get this in, so I'll do that and accept your answer once I do that. Thanks!